# jquery add and remove class (ul li)

Tags: jquery

When i click on a filter value in my webshop filter i want to add the .active class.

This works:

```
$(".filter ul li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

When i click twice i want to remove the .class. This does not work:

```
$(".filter ul li").click(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   if(myClass == "active") {
      $(this).removeClass();
   }
   else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggleClass()` with classname as argument which needs to be toggled:

```
$(".filter ul li").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```